# How to clone a dataset structure (TFDQuery) in Delphi 10?

Tags: delphi, dataset, clone

Can anyone help me to clone a TFDQuery in run-time?  I'm coding in Delphi Tokyo ,  I have a Datamodule with a TFDQuery in which I defined all fields properties using  Fields Editor at design time, in this way my DBGrid1 that points to this a Datamodule of this dataset, has all columns properly formated (dislay names, width, format, order).  During run-time I need to create new instances of TFDQuery, TDatamodule  and link these new  objects with the Dbgrid1.  I need this new TFDQuery be identiical to the existing one defined at design-time in order to keep DBgrid1 with same display names, display width and display formats as the design-time!
I tried the following approaches to copy dataset field definitions :

**1st Approach :  Method Assign for TFDQuery (didn't work) **

```
type
  TFormDados = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    vconnection : TFDConnection;
    vdataset    : TFDQuery;
    vdatasource : Tdatasource;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormDados: TFormDados;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
Uses
      unitdata;

procedure TFormDados.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
     vconnection := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
     vconnection.Assign(Dtmodule.FDConGrafico);

     vdataset := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
     vdataset.Connection  := vconnection;

     vdataset.Assign(Dtmodule.FDQueryDados);  // Runtime Error : Cannot assign a TFDQuery to a TFDQuery
```

**2nd Approach : Assign FieldDefs from the existing Dataset to the new one - didn't work !**

```
 ...
 vdataset.FieldDefs.Assign(Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.FieldDefs);
 vdataset.sql         := Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.sql;
 vdataset.params      := Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.Params;
 vdataset.FieldDefs.Update;
 vdataset.CreateDataSet;
 vdatasource          := Tdatasource.create(nil);
 vdatasource.DataSet  := vdataset;

 dbgrid1.DataSource   := vdatasource;

 vdataset.close;
 vdataset.Params[0].Asinteger := strtoint(edit1.Text);
 vdataset.Params[1].Asinteger := strtoint(edit2.Text);

 vdataset.Open;
```

Althought Assign method had run, vdataset didn't receive the fields definitions of the existing FDQquery .   After  open the vdataset , DBGrid1  did not show the  columns sequence, labels and formats fro the source dataset , WHY ?

**3rd Approach - Copy fields definition, one by one - didn't work**

```
for i:=0 to Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.Fields.Count -1 do
 begin
       with vdataset.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
       begin
            Name        := Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.FieldDefs[i].Name;
            Datatype    := Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.FieldDefs[i].DataType;
            Displayname := Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.FieldDefs[i].Displayname;
            Fieldno     := Dtmodule.FDQueryDados.FieldDefs[i].FieldNo;
       end;
 end;

 vdataset.FieldDefs.Update;
 vdataset.CreateDataSet;

 vdatasource         := Tdatasource.create(nil);
 vdatasource.DataSet := vdataset;

 dbgrid1.DataSource := vdatasource;

 ...
```

This code lead to the same result as the approach 2nd, i.e., it run but after  opened vdataset , DBGrid1  did not show the  columns sequence, labels and formats fro the source dataset.

I appreciate your help to fix the above code OR to implement the right method to copy dataset fields definitions from one existing dataset to a new one.

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Then store and restore DB grid columns as well.

Comment: Try `CopyDataSet` with `[coStructure]`

Comment: @Jason, DB grid loses column information when you re-assign its data source. Code [like this](https://pastebin.com/rN4gG5w0) can help you to keep it. Field defs of the underlying dataset are just one part.

Comment: @Jason, tks !  I tried  the command you suggested : vdataset.CopyDataSet(Dtmodule.FDQueryDados, [coStructure]) but it raised error : [FireDAC][Phys][Ora]-306.Command text must not be empty.

Comment: @Vitoria, tks for the code link.  I've tried it and it solved partially !!  I could recover some parts of columns definitions from the original Dbgrid1 like order and visible visible columns, however display name, display formats it didn't recover.  Please remember that I've made the definitions at TFDQuery fields and this dataset was associated with a Tdatamodule which as linked to DBgrid. I haven't define DBgrid Columns !  I appreciate your help !

Comment: In your second approach, just use `vdataset.FieldDefs := DtModule.FDQueryDados.FieldDefs` instead of `.Assign` and it should work.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the tips.  Unfortunatelly NONE of them worked !  I observed that when I run the query of this runtime created dataset it overlaps all the existin definitions , even if I used the commands proposed : 1) vdataset.CopyDataSet , 2) vdataset.FieldDefs := DtModule.FDQueryDados.FieldDefs , 3) save and restore DBgrid Columns definitions. **Is there any way to copy existing field definitions from a design time dataset  to a newly runtime created dataset ?**  I count on your help !! Thanks

Comment: I think you're asking if you can copy Persistent fields.. I'd have to run some tests..

Comment: Hi guys... does anyone have any other recomendation for me to solve this issue ?   Any help is very welcome !

Answer (score 2):

When you use the Fields editor for queries you are creating Fields not FieldDefs. From what I can tell the FieldDefs are kept in sync with the FieldsCollection when the component is created (or maybe opened not 100% sure). The Display* properties are not available on the FieldDef object - they only exist on the Field object. When you go to copy the structure you need to iterate the fields. The the method we use is below.

Note that the loop and the items created are "Fields", but we use a temporary FieldDef object to make the code simpler. The TFieldDef.CreatField serves as a class factory method to get the correct type of field i.e. TIntegerField vs TStringField. Also if you are using calculated fields you will need to hookup the OnCalcField event. This method does not do that.

```
procedure CopyFieldStructure(Source: TDataSet; Target: TDataset);
{^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^}
var
  Field: TField;
  NewField: TField;
  FieldDef: TFieldDef;
begin
  Target.Fields.Clear;
  Target.FieldDefs.Clear;

  // Cannot perform the next operation on an opened dataset
  if Target.State <> dsInactive then
    Target.Close;

  for Field in Source.Fields do
  begin
    // We are going to setup the first part in a FieldDef
    // that will set us use the CreateField Call in order to
    // get the correct subclass of TField created.
    FieldDef := Target.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef;
    FieldDef.DataType := Field.DataType;
    FieldDef.Size := Field.Size;
    FieldDef.Name := Field.FieldName;

    NewField := FieldDef.CreateField(Target);
    NewField.Visible := Field.Visible;
    NewField.DisplayLabel := Field.DisplayLabel;
    NewField.DisplayWidth := Field.DisplayWidth;
    NewField.EditMask := Field.EditMask;
    NewField.Calculated := Field.Calculated;
  end;
end;
```

Here is a similar StackOverflow question. I think this is where I originally took my code from: [Is there some better way to copy all DataSet Fields and their properties to another DataSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378737/is-there-some-better-way-to-copy-all-dataset-fields-and-their-properties-to-anot)

And here is one other blog post that uses a similar approach: [How to: Clone TField and TDataset fields structure](http://delphi-inspired.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-clone-tfield-and-tdataset-fields.html)

Also don't get fooled by the TDataSet.CopyField method. The help makes it seem like it could copy the field structure. When really it copies the current field "values" for any matching field names.

Comment: +1, however, if a property such as TFloatField.DisplayFormat needs to be copied, NewField.Datatype should be checked and cast accordingly ex. `TFloatField(NewField).DisplayFormat := TFloatField(Field).DisplayFormat`